NextJS 13 revalidatePath() working for created comments but not for created posts
I'm having trouble figuring out why revalidatePath() works in my CommentForm component but not in my PostForm component. I have made both components very similar in structure: createComment() will create a comment for a post or photo, while createPost() will create a post. Both functions activate when a form is submitted and both components are server components. I just do not understand why only one will use revalidatePath() correctly when they are practically the same.
CommentForm:
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import prisma from "../../../prisma/lib/prisma";

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

// Components
import Button from '../Button';

interface CommentFormProps {
  type: string;
  id: number;
}

const CommentForm: React.FC<CommentFormProps> = async ({ type, id }) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const createComment = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server"

    const content = formData.get("content") as string;
    const username = session!.user.username!;
  
    switch(type) {
      case "Photo": {
        try {
          const foundPhoto = await prisma.photo.findFirst({
            where: {
              id: id
            },
            select: {
              id: true
            }
          });

          if(foundPhoto) {
            await prisma.comment.create({
              data: {
                content: content,
                authorUsername: username,
                photoId: foundPhoto.id
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Photo not found');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Failed to fetch photo: ', e);
        }
        break;
      }
      case "Post": {
        try {
          const foundPost = await prisma.post.findFirst({
            where: {
              id: id
            },
            select: {
              id: true
            }
          });

          if(foundPost) {
            await prisma.comment.create({
              data: {
                content: content,
                authorUsername: username,
                postId: foundPost.id
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Post not found');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Failed to fetch post: ', e);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    revalidatePath('/');
  }

  return (
    <form action={createComment} className="flex flex-col text-center w-3/4 sm:w-1/2 m-auto mt-4">
      <label htmlFor="content" className="mb-3">
        New Comment<br />
        <textarea id="content" name="content" className="border border-gray-800 rounded-lg w-full text-black" rows={4} required />
      </label>
      <Button label="Add Comment" isDisabled={false} />
    </form>
  )
}

export default CommentForm;

PostForm:
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import prisma from "../../../prisma/lib/prisma";

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

// Components
import Button from '../Button';

const PostForm = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const createPost = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server"

    const content = formData.get("content") as string;

    try {
      await prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          content: content,
          author: {
            connect: {
              username: session?.user.username
            }
          }
        }
      });
      revalidatePath('/');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failed to create post: ', e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center gap-4'>
      <form className="flex flex-col text-center w-3/4 sm:w-1/2 m-auto" action={createPost}>
        <label htmlFor="content" className="mb-3">
          New Post<br />
          <textarea 
            id="content" 
            name="content" 
            className="border border-gray-800 rounded-lg w-full text-black" 
            rows={4} 
            maxLength={750} 
            required 
          />
        </label>
        <Button label="Add Post" isDisabled={false} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostForm;


maybe your try block is failing

Nope just tested with a console.log() within the try block. It works

This is a problem (or not a problem?) with revalidatePath not working in try-catch blocks, you should use it outside of it.
1 - A way around this is using it in finally statement, after controlling it with a check flag. You can see the below example to improvise.
2 - Or what is suggested is after performing an async operation, according to the result, revalidate, redirect, etc.


const createPost = async(formData: FormData) => {
  "use server"

  const content = formData.get("content") as string;

  let flag = false;

  try {
    await prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        content: content,
        author: {
          connect: {
            username: session ? .user.username
          }
        }
      }
    });
    flag = true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create post: ', e);
  } finally {
    if (flag) {
      revalidatePath("/");
    }
  }
};



